# How To Get Two Variable Values Loop Wise In C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to insert two variables foreach loop wise into database.how to do it?

```
foreach (string item in split)
{
val = item;
foreach (string uid in useid)
{
useval = uid;
}
command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "Insert_SentSMS";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentTime", sentTime);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", val);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", useval);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsType", "Manual");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsText", smsText);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationId", lblCustomSMSRegId.Text);
command.Connection = connection;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

i tried like above but 'useval ' value getting same not other values..

Comment: Please be more elaborate when asking a question. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Put your braces correctly and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either go for [comma-seperated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215426/passing-comma-separated-value-from-net-to-stored-procedure-using-the-value-in) or use [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you could correctly format your code, you find your solution yourself.

Your code clearly has 2 `{` but 3 `}`. That means, you either forget one `{` in your code or you didn't mentioned us.

You are executing your command outside of your 
`foreach (string uid in useid)` statement. That means, only the last value will be executed as a `useval` .

Move your executing code part in to;

```
foreach (string item in split)
{
    val = item;
    foreach (string uid in useid)
    {
        useval = uid;
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Insert_SentSMS";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentTime", sentTime);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", val);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", useval);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsType", "Manual");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsText", smsText);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationId", lblCustomSMSRegId.Text);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

By the way, don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` overloads to specify your `SqlDbType` and your parameter size. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command.

Comment: if i do like this then how to get differently 'val' value?

Comment: in val and useval i am getting array of values and wanna insert these values into database loop wise

Comment: @dawoodabbas This will be inside of your `foreach (string item in split)` statement as well. That's why you are iterating your `item` and `uid` as well. Check again.

Comment: so how to get two variable values at one like. foreach(string item in split && string uid in useid)

Comment: @dawood: no one asked and you still didn't make clear what your intention is. edit your question to give an example. So: What is your intent? if you actually have the same number of items in split and useid and you want to save the pairs matching the index, use a for(i=0..sizeof(arrays)) and access both arrays by split[i] and useid[i] to create the queries.

Comment: can u give and example plz

Comment: @dawood: no. before I will add any more code to this question, the intent should be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You re-assing `useVal` in ever loop. Here´s how you may achieve it:

```
foreach (string item in split)
{
    val = item;
    foreach (string uid in useid)
    {
        useval = uid;
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Insert_SentSMS";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentTime", sentTime);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", val);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", useval);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsType", "Manual");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsText", smsText);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationId", lblCustomSMSRegId.Text);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

However I´m not sure if creating a database-query in a loop is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop is wrong:

```
foreach (string uid in useid)
{
    useval = uid;
}
```

This does not make any sense (you are iterating all items without doing anything with them), you probably mean to do something like:

```
 foreach (string item in split)
 {
     val = item;
     foreach (string uid in useid)
     {
         useval = uid;

         command = new SqlCommand();
         command.CommandText = "Insert_SentSMS";
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentTime", sentTime);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", val);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", useval);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsType", "Manual");
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smsText", smsText);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationId", lblCustomSMSRegId.Text);
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```