# Pass String to SQL Statement In Condition

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I have a string which is having values in the following format

```
A , B, C
```

I need to pass this to a SQL statement's in condition as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE colname in ('A','B','C')
```

How can I do this?
I am not using PreparedStatement, plain SQL is being used.

Comment: You'll probably have the best results from using dynamic SQL

Comment: @RichBenner What are the other options?

Comment: you could take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215426/passing-comma-separated-value-from-net-to-stored-procedure-using-the-value-in

Comment: @RichBenner I am using Oracle database.

Comment: then tag it with oracle the first time you ask, we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `oracle` you can use `regexp_substr` to achieve this. See below:

For example the input string is `'A,B,C'`.

This can be achieved by splitting the comma separated string to individual strings and pass it to the IN clause.

First, we will form a query, that splits this comma separated string and gives the individual strings as rows.

```
Select regexp_substr('A,B,C' ,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                connect by regexp_substr('A,B,C' ,'[^,]+', 1, level is not null
```

The above query iterates through the comma separated string, searches for the comma (,) and then splits the string by treating the comma as delimiter. It returns the string as a row, whenever it hits a delimiter.

We can pass this query to our select statement to get the desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE colname in (
                Select regexp_substr('A,B,C' ,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                connect by regexp_substr('A,B,C' ,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like as below,

```
select * from mytable where col like 'A%'
union
select * from mytable where col like 'B%'
union
select * from mytable where col like 'C%';
```

you can also check the oracle 10g REGEXP_LIKE for more details.

[Link for more Details on REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I am using Oracle database

Answer (score 1):

You could create a stored proceedure, and use this to split the string into a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[stringSplit]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
)
SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
    'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
FROM Split
)
```

You can then query the data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE colname in (SELECT DATA FROM dbo.stringSplit(colname, ','))
```

This solution is written for MS SQL.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database, not MS SQL

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I am using Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use execute string.

MSSql syntax:

```
DECLARE  myColumns  @String NVARCHAR(4000) = 'A,B,C';

EXECUTE 'SELECT '+ myColumns +' FROM mytable '
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I am using Oracle database.